# How to insert values into bridge table (made of 2 Foreign Key rows) on T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have a bridge table called book_author with 2 rows: Book_ISBN (which is a Foreign Key from Books table) and Author_ID (Foreign key from Author table).

```
CREATE TABLE Book_Author (
    Book_ISBN BIGINT,
    Author_ID BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Book_Author PRIMARY KEY (Book_ISBN, Author_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_B_A_Book_ISBN FOREIGN KEY (Book_ISBN) REFERENCES Book(Book_ISBN),
    CONSTRAINT FK_B_A_Author_ID FOREIGN KEY (Author_ID) REFERENCES Author(Author_ID)
)
```

I want to insert the values from those tables into the bridge table (book_author). This worked, but affected 0 rows, therefore didn't add any data:

```
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID)
SELECT book.Book_ISBN, author.Author_ID
FROM Book_Author
INNER JOIN Book ON Book_Author.Book_ISBN = Book.Book_ISBN 
INNER JOIN Author on Book_Author.Author_ID = Author.Author_ID
```

As the mentioned rows (from books table and author table) already have data, I thought T-SQL would automatically insert those values into book_author table (and with the same column-names).

```
INSERT INTO Book (Book_ISBN, Book_Name, Publisher_ID, Edition, Language, Genre, Year_Published)
VALUES  ('9780261103573', 'The Fellowship of the Ring', '1', '1', 'English', 'Fantasy Fiction', '1954'),
        ('9780007203550', 'The Two Towers', '1', '1', 'English', 'Fantasy fiction', '1960'),
        ('9780007129720', 'The Return of the King', '1','1', 'English', 'Fantasy fiction', '1965'),
        ('9780399900709', 'The Bourne Identity', '2', '3', 'English', 'Spy thrillers', '1980'),
        ('9788563560520', 'Quincas Borba', '3', '5', 'Portuguese', 'Romance', '1982'),
        ('9782864972662', 'Astérix chez les Pictes', '4', '3', 'French', 'Adventure comic books', '2012');

INSERT INTO Author (Author_ID, Author_FName, Author_LName)
VALUES  (1, 'Tolkien', 'J.R.R.'),
        (2, 'Robert', 'Ludlum'),
        (3, 'Machado', 'de Assis'),
        (4, 'Jean-Yves', 'Ferri');
```

Comment: Please provide sample data you want to insert in to Book_Author table

Comment: Since the `book_author` Link table doesn't have any values yet (if I understand correctly), then you cannot possibly use a JOIN on that table to get any values....... so given your list of books and authors - how do you know which authors belong to which book (so you can insert those values into the link table) ?!? That's exactly the purpose of the link table, so if you want to create the values in that table - how do you determine which authors belong to which books??

Comment: Your selecting data from a table you want to insert into? Are you sure it has data? And carefull with inner join as it removes all which doesnt map. Can we see your Book_autor table?

Comment: Hi @marc_s, what I thought was that the book_author table would automatically populate from the book and author tables, since they are foreign keys from those tables. Like if in a piece of paper I could cut one row from each of those tables and "glue" them together side-by-side. Forgive me if I'm not explaining properly and thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: No, there's nothing "automagic" here - you have n books and m authors - ***HOW*** do they belong together?? That's exactly what that link table should define - but you cannot just **automagically** get this done - **YOU** have to define which author(s) belongs to which book(s) and insert the appropriate rows into the link table to establish those connections!

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use join in simple insert query?

```
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID) VALUES ('9780261103573','1')
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID) VALUES ('9780007203550','1')
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID) VALUES ('9780007129720','1')
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID) VALUES ('9780399900709','2')
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID) VALUES  ('9780399900709','2')
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID) VALUES ('9782864972662','4')
```

Comment: Hi, How can we run above set of queries dynmically in loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement reads from a select that has 0 rows on the FROM table followed by inner join thus the results will always be 0 rows. Even if the bridge table had rows those would be selected but could not be inserted either because of the primary key violation, as you attempt to insert data that already exists.

I assume that you have some other column somewhere hold this relation i suppose at the books, something like Book.Author_ID. In that case you need:

```
INSERT INTO Book_Author (Book_ISBN, Author_ID)SELECT Book.Book_ISBN, Book.Author_ID FROM Book GROUP BY Book.Book_ISBN, Book.Author_ID
```

If you also have additional info e.g. at Author table create a similar SELECT, use GROUP BY to make sure you get distinct values and use UNION for the two select statements to make sure you also get distinct values from both SELECT statements.

This is to fill existing relations. For new books you have to use a simple insert statement as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert into a bridging table in bulk like so:

insert into bookauthors (Book_Id, Author_Id)
(
select
'C3004DD0-2946-4C8D-BDE0-B3BE70EFF601',
Id
from books
where
{condition}
)